# warning messages: replacing previous import by plyr:: when loading my package

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I am developing an R package called `MyPkgName` which imports both `plyr` and `dplyr`. When I build and install my package, I get the following warning messages:

```
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::arrange’ when loading ‘MyPkgName’
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::desc’ when loading ‘MyPkgName’
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::failwith’ when loading ‘MyPkgName’
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::id’ when loading ‘MyPkgName’
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::mutate’ when loading ‘MyPkgName’
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::summarise’ when loading ‘MyPkgName’
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘plyr::summarize’ when loading ‘MyPkgName’
```

I am not sure if they result from importing both `plyr` and `dplyr` packages... I think I first import `plyr` and then import `dplyr`. Is there a way to get around this? I use several functions in each of the packages. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK loading both is not recommended.

Comment: Don't import both packages. Use `importFrom` to import selectively.